# Making list that takes in value if value appears more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, append

If my list has values that appears more than once I want to do the following:

```py
my_list = ['a','b','c','a','a','b']
```

I want that `my_list` becomes `['a','b','c']`
and at the same time `new_list = ['a','a','b']`

I have started with the code but can't manage to finish it:

```
def func(word):
    tgt = 1
    found = []
    lst = [1,2,3,45,6,1]
    if lst.count(word)> 1:
        found.append(word)
    return found, lst
print(func(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the list, store the element in one list if it is not visited or in a new list if it is already visited:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','a','a','b']
visited, lst, new_list = set(), [], []
for x in my_list:
    if x not in visited:
        lst.append(x)
        visited.add(x)
    else:
         new_list.append(x)
         
print(lst, new_list)
# ['a', 'b', 'c'] ['a', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for`visited` to be a `set`/`dict` instead of `list`? Or the reason is since we only going to have 26 letters, the list search would be faster than set/dict?

Comment: @MaxMiller, Nice point. It would be rather efficient to use set for the membership check though I'd assume for a very few elements like in the OP's example, it won't greatly matter.

Comment: visited seems pointless, just use lst

Answer (score 1):

```py
my_list = ['a','b','c','a','a','b']
new_list = my_list.copy()

my_list = list(set(my_list))
my_list.sort()

# remove unique items from new_list
for item in my_list:
    new_list.pop(new_list.index(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use a `collections.Counter()` to count up the occurrences of each items in the list. At that point the `keys()` become your new `my_list` and then we will use some list multiplication to construct your `new_list`.

```py
import collections
data = ['a','b','c','a','a','b']
counted = collections.Counter(data)
```

At this point finding your new `my_list` is dead simple:

```py
my_list  = list(counted)
print(my_list)
```

gives you:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now we can leverage the fact that `['a'] * 4 == ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']` to construct a list from they keys of `counted` based on the number of times they were identified.

```py
new_list = []
for key, value in counted.items():
    if value > 1:
        new_list.extend([key]*(value-1))
print(new_list)
```

This will give us back:

```
['a', 'a', 'b']
```

**Full Solution:**

```py
import collections
data = ['a','b','c','a','a','b']
counted = collections.Counter(data)

my_list  = list(counted)
new_list = []
for key, value in counted.items():
    if value > 1:
        new_list.extend([key]*(value-1))

print(my_list, new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["a","b","a","c","d","b"]
new_list=[]
for i in lst:
    if i not in new_list: # check the new list if values repeat or not
        new_list.append(i) # add the repeating values in new list
for i in new_list: 
    if i in lst: 
        lst.remove(i) # remove the repeating values from first list
print(lst,new_list)
```

**at first you can add the repeating values in a different list then remove these values from your first list.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
  l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
  arr = []
  for x in l:
      if x not in a:
          arr.append(x)
  # now arr only have the non repeating elements of the array l
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30996486)

Comment: @Henrik: Why not?

Comment: first of all 'if x not in a:' gives 'NameError: name 'a' is not defined'
secondly, it only provdes the second list. (second half of question). You would need to also remove the letters added to 'a' from 'arr', and then sort 'arr', before the question was answerred.